# Machine Learning on Unclassified Data

Tags: machine-learning

So I am currently thinking about a problem with a friend that deals with classifying a huge list of statements (I cannot give more information for privacy reasons). My friend ran a K-means clustering algorithm on it and there seem to be groupings. I wanted to do a supervised approach but unfortunately, there always seem to be some possible inputs that will never be covered in any given training set. What ways are there to deal with this?

Comment: If your data is unclassified, you're not doing supervised learning.

Comment: 1) We probably can't help you without details, so if it is crucial to avoid providing details, you should probably hire a consultant rather than expecting to get an answer here.  Here, we require you to provide enough context that it is possible to provide a useful answer to the question.  2) It's not clear to me what is meant by "inputs that are not covered", or what you mean by "any given training set" (you have multiple training sets?).